# Writing to a .txt file and removing from a .txt file

Tags: python

```
Tables = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
Reserved = []

content = open('C:/Users/amaya/OneDrive/Desktop/CIS 2300/Reservations.txt', 'w+')
def remove(newT, table_reservations):
        newT = []
        for x in range(len(Tables)):
                if x != table_reservations:
                    newT.append(Tables[x-1])
        return newT

def add(Reserved, table_reservations):
    Reserved.append(table_reservations)
    print("Reserved tables (by number):",Reserved)
    return Reserved


print("1-Reserve table")
print("2-Clear reservation")
print("3-Report")
print("0-Exit program")

answer= input("What would you like to do?")   

if answer == '1':

    NAME = input("Name for reservation: ")
    table_reservations = int(input("What table would you like to reserve (1-19)?:  "))

    remove(Tables, table_reservations)
    add(Reserved, table_reservations)
    content.write(NAME)
    content.write(str(table_reservations))
    content.close

if answer == '2':
    content.read
    cancel= input("if you would like to cancel a reservation enter your name and table number: ")
    if cancel == content:
        remove(Reserved, cancel)
    print("Reservation has been canceled.")

if answer == '3':
    print(content)

if answer == '0':
    print("Goodbye!")
```

I'm trying to create a program that will take down the names and table number of the customer that will also  be able to delete that reservation off the .txt file. Writing into the file has only worked once for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

Read your file into a suitable structure and then overwrite it each time you want to make a change. Do not make changes to the file object.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are missing some brackets on the close

```
content.close()
```

And maybe you could also use a csv file or ans sqlite3 database with pandas that would make the task much much faster and easier.